# Why is patsy returning 2 columns for my left hand side?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, patsy

I'm using the [`patsy`](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) python package. I have a boolean dependent (y) variable, and some number of numerical explanatory variables. I'm hoping for patsy to treat my y variable as a categorical variable, and therefore produce a 1-hot encoding of the boolean data. However, even with a simple data frame and formula, it always produces two columns. This causes problems downstream in sklearn where certain classifiers need a single column. Here is an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import patsy
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [True, False, True, True], "x": [1, 1, 3, 4]})
>>> df
       y  x
0   True  1
1  False  1
2   True  3
3   True  4
>>> patsy.dmatrices("y ~ x", df)
(DesignMatrix with shape (4, 2)
y[False]  y[True]
       0        1
       1        0
       0        1
       0        1
Terms:
'y' (columns 0:2), DesignMatrix with shape (4, 2)
Intercept  x
        1  1
        1  1
        1  3
        1  4
Terms:
'Intercept' (column 0), 'x' (column 1))
```

Note how the y matrix has two columns.

How can I produce the result that I want, which is simply `1, 0, 1, 1`, but *using patsy* and not simply converting the series to an integer using numpy or pandas to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a solution is still needed, and this is a hacky approach, but you can use `patsy`'s [`categorical_to_int()`](https://github.com/pydata/patsy/blob/bd3c12a72ea3f3788983e0ebb9f35d16ae25b27d/patsy/categorical.py#L308) function.  It's a helper function for other design matrix building functions.

You just need to call the function inside the formula, with 3 positional arguments:

- data (in your case, the `y` column),
- a tuple of unique levels (with values listed in ascending numerical order, so `False` for 0, then `True` for 1),
- and the required instance of the `NAAction` class.

Note: The function will map any missing values to -1.

```
import pandas as pd
import patsy
from patsy.categorical import categorical_to_int
from patsy.missing import NAAction

df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [True, False, True, True], "x": [1, 1, 3, 4]})

patsy.dmatrices("categorical_to_int(y, (False, True), NAAction()) ~ x", df)
```

Output:

```
(DesignMatrix with shape (4, 1)
   categorical_to_int(y, (False, True), NAAction())
                                                  1
                                                  0
                                                  1
                                                  1
   Terms:
     'categorical_to_int(y, (False, True), NAAction())' (column 0),
 DesignMatrix with shape (4, 2)
   Intercept  x
           1  1
           1  1
           1  3
           1  4
   Terms:
     'Intercept' (column 0)
     'x' (column 1))
```